# Windows Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows, ip, windows-server-2012, remote-desktop

I have a Windows Server 2012 and I can currently connect to it via the built-in Windows remote desktop software.

I enter the server IP and password and all is fine. However, I was wondering what I can do in the server to only allow certain IP addresses to connect to the server. Is this even possible?

If not, are there any alternatives that can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality does not exist within the RDP protocol or the MS RDP/Terminal Services server.  The only real option to achieve this is with a firewall - an edge firewall, for example, but even the built in Windows firewall has this functionality.

[image]

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH, exactly what I need. So am I correct in sayng this should eliminate alot of security threats and no easy way to bypass it? if I only add my own IP address in there

Comment: Be careful adding your own IP address there if you're on a dynamic addressing system, like a consumer cable router or DHCP LAN; you'll be blocked from accessing RDP if your IP changes.

Comment: @user234360 Well, yeah, it's more secure than not having it, but no security is perfect.  And, as the comment above cautions, make sure you have a static IP before using this feature... and be warned that most residential ISPs don't offer this.  (After almost 2 years at the same IP, my ISP changed my IP a couple nights ago, and I'm now in a block that geo-IP identifies as being in a completely different state from where I live.)